# WSO2 Micro Integrator - custom fault sequence on ws-security errors

Tags: wso2, ws-security, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm trying to customize with WSO2 Micro Integrator the error response returned by a proxy service configured with ws-security policy (with custom Rampart configuration). If at example the client send invalid certificate, the default fault envelope is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> ... 
<soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault
        xmlns:axis2ns5="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <faultcode>axis2ns5:FailedCheck</faultcode>
        <faultstring>The signature or decryption was invalid (The provided certificate is invalid)</faultstring>
        <detail/>
    </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Changes to the default fault sequence or asscociate custom fault sequence to proxy service have no effect: any suggestions?

Affected version: WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.0.0

Thanks in advance.